# I need to deform a complex array

Tags: mesh

I need to build a regular structure (Think a three dimensional net) out of strings and deform it, as if it were slack in some spaces. This is supposed to be printed, so I need actual structure and no shaders.

This is a first sketch of what it's supposed to look like:

[image: Slacking web]

It is not as chaotic as it looks, this is the bottom view:

[image]

A short summary of what I did (in that order):

1. I created the string using the screw modifier on some circles.
2. I built curves for the knots and so on and had the strings follow them (curve
   modifier).
3. I used regular arrays to create the web.

And here's where my issues start, I tried multiple ways:

4a.:
I applied all modifiers, joined the meshes, then moved some vertices with
proportional editing active (That's what the pics show). This is what I am trying to
achieve, but not in such a small scale, but around 30 times the area that is shown.
With the computational ressources at my disposal, I'm not able to make this happen. I
need modifiers or reliable placeholders.

4b.:
I applied the Warp modifier, but it compresses the meshes too much.

So, to sum up, I need to deform a highly complex, three dimensional web before applying modifiers.

Another though I had was whether maybe I can slice the thing into smaller portions and work on them individually (Since it's going to be printed, it needs to be sliced into chunks eventually anyway), but then I'm not sure how to ensure that the cuts will line up later.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: if you are trying to deform the whole structure, you can do it with a Lattice modifier for example

Comment: That was indeed it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was Lattice deform modifier.